# DV360 API - list "Youtube & Partners" line items?

Tags: google-api, dv360

I'm trying to contact the ["advertisers.lineItems.list" API endpoint](https://developers.google.com/display-video/api/reference/rest/v1/advertisers.lineItems/list) of the Display Video 360 (DV360) Google APIs.

The problem is that even if the call works as intendend, I cannot seem to retrieve any Line Item from the "YouTube & partners" list, so far I'm getting those from "Display" and "Video" networks.

This behaviour is the same in the [GET](https://developers.google.com/display-video/api/reference/rest/v1/advertisers.lineItems/get) API call, if I try to request a Youtube Line Item, the API returns a 404 code.

Is there a parameter I'm missing or maybe a different endpoint to retrieve those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official response from their support:

> Management of YouTube & Partners resources, including creation, retrieval and updating, is currently not available through the DV360 API.
>
> If you are looking to retrieve YouTube & Partner resources, that can be done by [generating and downloading SDFs using the API](https://developers.google.com/display-video/api/guides/downloading-sdfs/create).

So if you just need to retrieve them you could try the second method. But you won't be able to modify them programmatically through the API.